# Prevent id from being specified on POST call

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I would like an EF entity to be created by a POST call in WebAPI.

should the controller method look like:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(entity))]
public IHttpActionResult Post(entity e)
{
   ...
}
```

Where the `entity` class contains a property for `ID` which is the auto-increment primary key.

I don't want the `Post` method to be called with a entity object that has the `ID` property set.

What methods are available to me to stop an object posted for creation containing a primary key?

Comment: what experience are you going for? Do you want to return an error to the client or do you want the id property ignored??

Comment: I think an error is fine. Is this not a common issue? If is uncommon i am probably doing something wrong. I suspect i shouldn't expose this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me see if I understand you correctly... You want to:

1. do a `POST` to your Web API service,
2. pass an entire, pre-populated EF `entity` **without** an ID field as a parameter, and
3. return the same entity with the ID field populated after being assigned an auto-incremented value from the database?

If the above sounds at least close to what you want, then I'd say it's a common issue but you're going about it in an uncommon way.

Let's say your `entity` looks like this:

```
public class entity
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
}
```

So, let me now explain your options as I see them:

1. If your `entity` object is very simple as above, then you can pass the `firstname` and `lastname` parameters in the URI by adding the `[FromUri]` attribute to all parameters in your method definition and adjust your client code to pass this information as a query string in the URI.
2. If your `entity` object is much more complex than my simplistic example above, then you can create a DTO (Data Transfer Object) that contains all the EF model parameters you need to pass to your database to create the `entity` *except* the `ID`, i.e. just `firstname` and `lastname` in this case, and pass that to the `Post` method as a (`[FromBody]`) parameter and adjust your client code to pass this information in the request body (probably as simple JSON).

You can then return *just* the auto-incremented ID from the database and not your entire `entity`, since you already have all the other information anyway (since you already passed it to your service's `Post` method as a parameter!).